# iOS document scanning and stitching from multiple images

Tags: ios, iphone-app, scanning, ipad-app, stitching

Is there an app for iOS that will do one of these?

- scan a large document by guiding the user to take multiple photos of a document such as a large poster and then combine them automatically
- stitch multiple existing photos together automatically to create a single image

Would a panorama stitching app also work for this or is it assumed that the camera stays fixed and rotates around the focal point?

My main interest is in getting a very high quality copy of the original document such that I can zoom in and see details well.

Answer (score 0):

[Hugin](https://wiki.panotools.org/Hugin) can easily do what you are looking for including:

- Stitching together images in any order
- Producing very large image files
- Perspective correction
- Rotation correction
- Exposure correction

It is:

- Free, Gratis & Open Source
- Cross Platform including OS-X, Windows & Linux **but** I have not found a build that runs on iOS so you would need an online option or another computer.

Until there is an iOS build you would need to transfer your photos to a desktop or laptop and perform the stitching there or use an online service such as the [OnLineAppBox Hugin App](https://www.onlineappbox.com/online-hugin.htm).

Comment: I always like to know about high quality open source software but for now I'd like to create the image on my iPad (or iPhone) and annotate directly there with an Apple Pencil.

Answer (score 0):

Adobe has a free ios app named Mix. It will let you merge many images into one. The downside is the desktop counterpart is Photoshop which is not cheap. Maybe Mix will meet all your needs, however. The app features tutorials to get you up to speed.